# kineticjs how to use attrs

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

Im very new to kineticjs and js, And i want to know how to use values in the attrs

I have this code

```
BubbleLayer.on('mouseover mousemove dragmove', function(evt) {
        var node = evt.targetNode;
        console.log(node)
        if (node) {`enter code here`
          // update tooltip
          var mousePos = node.getStage().getPointerPosition();
          tooltip.position({x:mousePos.x, y:mousePos.y - 5});
          tooltip.getText().text("Project: " + node.id() + ", Hours: " + **need to show hours **());
          tooltip.show();
          tooltipLayer.batchDraw();
        }
```

The console log shows (see image below)
[image]

I want to dispay the totalHours in the above code

```
tooltip.getText().text("Project: " + node.id() + ", Hours: " + **need to show hours **());
```

But dont know where to start. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What does `console.log(node.attrs.totalHours)` output? (It looks like an object)

Comment: Thats it. Perfect. ( now i feel silly)

Comment: Cool, I left it as an answer. Good luck with Kinetic, you can do some pretty awesome stuff with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a javascript object. You should be able to access it with `node.attrs.totalHours`.